# Xcode 7 warnings with Google Signin lib when building project

Tags: ios, xcode, google-signin

I got this issue warnings on `Xcode 7` (C*ould not resolve external type ...*) . I Google it and did all found solutions but did not solve the issue.

The Google SignIn lib was added via Pods (pod 'Google/SignIn').

See following image link for detail warnings info.

[Warnings on Xcode 7 with Google SignIn lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElUbu.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did found root cause. It seem GoogleSignIn lib has problem with setting "Debug Information Format" if it was set value "DWARF with dSYM File". If you set value to "DWARF" (for Run app in Debug or Release configuration), the warnings gone. But that is not expected solution, we need dSYM File for debugging issues.

More further info, I set "Debug Information Format" for Debug is "DWARF" and for Release is "DWARF with dSYM File". If run app in debug configuration, no warnings appear. If run app in release configuration, the warnings appear.

[image: Screenshot for "Debug Information Format" value.]

Comment: This only _avoids_ seeing the issue since you don't end up creating a dSYM, this does not _fix_ the issue. Also, you will need a dSYM on debug builds if you use bug reporting services such as Crashlytics and care about things like symbolication for your alpha/beta debug builds.

Answer (score 3):

I've also run into this issue since updating to GoogleSignIn 3.3.0+ on Xcode 7 and 7.0.1.

The only usefull solution I've found so far, which didn't end up helping me was to use these settings from [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17921) It may work for you.

```
 - Precompile Prefix (GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER) = NO Debug
 - Information Format (DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT) = DWARF with dSYM
 - Enabled Modules (C and Objective-C) (CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES) = NO
```

Comment: Thanks for your info, but for me can not set 'Enable Modules' = NO because there are many header files use "@import XXX". The 'Precompile Prefix' use for compile .pch prefix file, also can not set NO too. Still waiting solutions...

Comment: For reference, XCode 7.1 beta 3 yields no different results. The warnings persist.

Comment: I got away with just `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = NO` and `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULE_DEBUGGING = NO`

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.4.0 of the GoogleSignIn library corrects this issue (Finally! :))

Comment: Should this not be the true marked answer? everything else here doesn't actually fix the problem, it only hides it.

Answer (score 0):

I have silenced the warnings by setting the debug information format to DWARF just for **Debug**.

```
- Information Format (DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT) = DWARF
```

Personally I am not fond of this and do not know if there are other side effects. If anyone can comment on possible negative side effects I will be happy to read.

EDIT:
I have found that others are using this solution as well. See MikeElardVS's comment [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17921#58073).

EDIT2:
As in answer by blahartinger I can confirm that the GoogleSignin lib has been updated to not show these warnings anymore. Will remove the above workaround. Thanks blahartinger for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks Reggian, your info is useful.

Comment: Not a real solution as mentioned above.